# A very long delay between indexing a document in ElasticSearch and seeing it in search results

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

We are experiencing a problem with ES 5.4.2 on production. About 25% of our indexed documents are only appearing in search results after 3 seconds or more after success response from indexing request. For some documents, it's more than 7 seconds. Our cluster consists of three nodes with 59GBs of RAM of which 31GBs are dedicated to ES heap. Heap usage never goes over 75% with GC dropping it down to ~25-30%. Indexing rate is relatively low, less than 10 documents per second. Our average refresh time is ~300 ms. Refresh interval is default 1s.

With these numbers, I am expecting at most ~1.5 s delay between indexation and search availability. What am I missing here? Is it possible to reduce this search availability delay? Maybe I'm missing some metric that is worth monitoring?

Comment: You shoud monitor indices flush&merge with `GET /_nodes/stats/indices`, flush&refresh thread pool queues `GET /_cat/thread_pool` . Are you updating/deleting docs or inserting new docs?

Comment: Thank you for your advice about thread pools. It has shown something interesting: there is no queue for neither merge, index or flush pools, but some search pool is definitely spiking. I will try to dig up why is it this way.

Comment: Long index-search delay happens both for new documents and for updated documents. In my benchmark, I only insert new documents, but application makes both inserts and updates. We see these long delays both in application and benchmark.

Comment: what about the refresh_interval did you check that ? its usually controlled by the index settings/template ?